# How do you awaken the Ancient One by opening the gate of Kadath?

Tags: arkham-horror

The [Arkham Horror Statistics spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AliZyklaTCWzcGFQTWdvZW5jc1JwcHEzUEVZV1htUVE&hl=en_US#gid=7) lists one of the ways to awaken the Ancient One as "Opening the gate of Kadath". To date, it has never been achieved and I'm curious about why. I took a look through all of [the encounter cards for Unknown Kadath](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Unknown_Kadath) but didn't see any that referenced opening a gate that would awaken the Ancient One.

So how does one open the gate of Kadath and why is it so difficult that it has never been accomplished yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's talking about [this encounter](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/File%3AGate101.png):

> **Unknown Kadath**
>
> In response to your pitiful knocking, the massive gate of the Castle of the Great Old Ones swings wide. Lose 1 Stamina and 1 Sanity. If you are devoured as a result, the Ancient One immediately awakens.

It's a literal physical gate in the encounter, not a gate like the ones that open normally during the game. And for some reason you decide to knock on it. Pretty hard to awaken the Ancient One that way - you have to manage to get that encounter *and* already be at 1 Stamina and 1 Sanity.